# Displaying recommendations on a Communities page for guest users

Tags: community-builder, einstein

I'm trying to get an answer for one of my clients who is looking at using Einstein Next Best Action on a Communities page to [display recommendations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=nba_admin_using_strategies.htm&type=5).

They want to know if this feature only works for authenticated users, or whether it's also available for guest users.

I see from [the documentation](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_networks_nba_pilot.htm) that when a user accepts a suggested offer, a screen flow is launched. So, I guess my question is can you enable a screen flow for a guest user?